# Best way to organize data from multiple companies in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, business-intelligence, powerbi-datasource, data-preprocessing

Basically I have a big Excel dataset about 500x500 with economic information from various companies.

Each row is representing a different company and in columns we have the information. A little bit of it is qualitative like ZIP code, type, etc. But most of it is quantitative. For each of the quantitative info, we have info for 5 years, so we have one column for each year and for each information i.e. Debt 2019, Debt 2020, etc.

So my question is which is the best way to preprocess this data to work with it and how should it be done. Either doing the preprocessing with Excel, running a Script on PowerBI, using Query, SQL, ...

The objective is to have a report which will be accessible online and the user will type the name of the company and it will show them the dashboard with the information of that company (only that one), so they can navigate through it.

The structure and which information is shown is the same for each company, the only thing that changes is the "numbers" that each company has.  So it has to be possible to change which data is showing (to use the one from the company they want).

It also needs to be able to show comparative data to other groups of companies or to the total.

I want to have it right from the start, because then changes get complicated.

I thought about doing sort of a "relational model" with one "table" for each company with the quantitative data (with one row for each year and each column one info point) and then a general table with the qualitative data (with rows being each company and the columns the info). But I am not really sure.

I know how to use Power BI but I have never used it for something this big. I would like to know which way to organize this data is better and some info on how to do it.

Many thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought about doing sort of a "relational model" with one "table" for each company with the quantitative data (with one row for each year and each column one info point) and then a general table with the qualitative data (with rows being each company and the columns the info).

Yes, do that.

General guidance is to use Power Query in PowerBI to transform the data into a star schema model.  See [Understand star schema and the importance for Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/star-schema)

So that would typically result in one table that has the "dimension" data for each company, a date table, and a "fact" table at the grain of (CompanyId,Date) with the quantitative data.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much thats been helpful. I have been reading on the matter. The quantiative data are mostly financial ratios for each companny.

So what you suggest is having two dimension tables: one for the years, with each year and one for the companies, with each company and it's qualitative information.
Then have one fact table with first two columns: DateID, CompanyID and then one column for each ratio? Am I right?

I guess having it the other way around, meaning one dimension table for each ratio and the companies info at the center in the fact table is not advisable, right?

Comment: "hen have one fact table with first two columns: DateID, CompanyID and then one column for each ratio?"  Yes.  And no need to @mention an answer or question author; they get notified automatically.